# How to check if a file exists while using a Scanner in Java

Tags: java, file, input

So, if you go down to my `createdChoice` method, you will see I am trying to figure out how to have a `User` type in a file and see if it exists.

This is what I have so far.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException; 
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MadLibs {

  public static void main(String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    File madLibFile = new File("/Users/adanvivero/IdeaProjects/Assignment 4/src/mymadlib.txt");
    Scanner madLib = new Scanner(System.in);

    String choice = menu(console);
    if(choice.equals("c")) {
      createdChoice(madLib);
    }
  }

  public static void createdChoice(Scanner madLib) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File madLibFile = new File("/Users/adanvivero/IdeaProjects/Assignment 4/src/mymadlib.txt");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner fileName = new Scanner(madLibFile);
    System.out.print("Input file name: ");
    String fileAccess = input.next();
    //fileName = madLibFile;
    if(fileAccess.equals(fileName)) {
        System.out.print("Well this file exists, but I don't know how to make it into a scanner");
    }
  }
}
```

I hope this makes sense. Provide some feedback

Comment: I know an easier way to do this. I will post it when I have time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check whether the file or directory denoted by provided pathname exists you can use `exist()` :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  final File file  = new File("temp/foo.txt");
  if (file.exists()) {
    System.out.printf("File " + file.getName() + " exist !");
  }
}
```

Not let's take a look at our `Scanner` :

```
public Scanner(File source) throws FileNotFoundException {}
```

If you pass a file to the Scanner which does not exist - you will get an exception.

So to ensure that file exists in this case you can :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  // let's say there is no such file
  final File file  = new File("temp/foo.txt");
  try {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file); // this will fail if file does not exist
    // otherwise it exist and you can do what you want
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // and here you can handle the case when file not exist
  }
}
```

If you mean how to check if your scanner can fetch something, scanner has a lot of `hasNext...` methods. Like `hasNext()`, `hasNextByte()`, `hasNextLine()`, etc.

And before you do `scanner.next()` you should check! e.g. :

```
if (scanner.hasNext()) {
  String fileAccess = scanner.next();  
}
```

These lines in your code are wrong because you try to check if 2 different types String and Scanner are `equals()`. They never are.

```
// fileAccess is String and fileName is Scanner according to your code
if(fileAccess.equals(fileName)) {
  System.out.print("Well this file exists, but I don't know how to make it into a scanner");
}
```

How I would rewrite your piece of code (but not sure I understand what exactly it should do), so just as an example:

```
public static void createdChoice() throws FileNotFoundException {
  File madLibFile = new File("/Users/adanvivero/IdeaProjects/Assignment 4/src/mymadlib.txt");
  if (madLibFile.exist()) {
    Scanner inScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(madLibFile);
    System.out.println("Input file name: " + madLibFile.getName());
    if (inScanner.hasNext()) {
      String fileAccess = inScanner.next();
      // do whatever you need e.g
      if(fileAccess.equals(madLibFile.getName())) {
        // something here
      }
    } else {
      System.out.println("No more tokens to read !");  
    }
  } else {
    System.out.println("File mymadlib.txt does not exist !");
  }
}
```

Hope this is somehow helpful.

Happy hacking :)

Comment: What I am trying to figure out is this. To put it in simple terms.

I ask the user to input a file name. 
The user inputs a file name randomly. 

I want to know is how do I know if the file the user entered exists in order to move forward. That's my question.

Comment: I'm still messing around with this, and I'll get back to you with some updates.

Comment: I figured out an easier way to do this. I will post it when I have time .